# delete csv's in different folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, directory

I have a lot of files in different folders that I need to delete.

Generally I have been using:

```
  try:
        for file in ['C:\\14\\13.csv', 'C:\\54\\13.csv', 'C:\\64\\14.csv', 'C:\\44\\55.csv']
                os.remove(file)
    except OSError as e:
        pass
```

However, if it can't find a file it just moves on to the next part of the script which means it is not a good solution.   I need to delete all the files.  Any idea how this can be achieved?  Perhaps using a different try, except?

Thanks.

Comment: Move the `try` block _inside_ the loop, around `os.remove(file)`

Comment: @mshsayem Under for file?  It gives me red errors if I do that.  Can you show with example I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `try` block inside the loop like this:

```
for file in [r'C:\14\13.csv', r'C:\54\13.csv', r'C:\64\14.csv', r'C:\44\55.csv']:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except Exception as e: # catch all exceptions
        pass
```